# Ember return to REST server for complete field set

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So theres an route/view that only needs to show the name and id field. If and when a single model is selected then I need to re-fetch only that model (by id) but requesting more fields. With the default DS.Store, it finds the model by the id and foregoes the second full trip to the backend.

Is there an accepted method of marking a model as 'incomplete' and im not talking about this [todo incomplete](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ember-data store is just a local cache of objects of data already retrieved from the server and any that have been created or updated so far by the client. The methods on the store deal with the management of this "cache" on the application level.

When you call `.find()` on the store it will first check that local cache, and if it has the object already there it will return that. You are probably working with a record which already exists in the store, presumably because you just created it. Ember-data doesn't do "partial" models; you load a model in its entirety.

So I think what you're looking for is the `DS.Store.fetch()` method: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_fetch

Comment: It's worth reiterating this point by @Leeft's: **Ember-data doesn't do "partial" models; you load a model in its entirety.** I believe that is one of the core principals of the JSON API spec, which Ember Data implements.

Comment: there is no way of marking a model as dirty but not for the usual 'needs writing' but for needs additional reading?!

Comment: You can't, no. You can only tell ember-data that it must be retrieved again.

Comment: disagree with the partial model. even the must-have pagination defies that partial model concept. its a slice of the the large picture. and many nosql backed projects have verbose data schemas with repeated data that doesnt need to be loaded in the first gulp. it would really make this fat front end even fatter.

Comment: hopefully it will overwrite the first object despite the same ID. thanks btw

Comment: It's "not partial" in the sense that you have to load all of one "document" at once rather than just a few select fields of said document. You could have a JSON API return only a selection of fields, but ember-data still doesn't support that. And pagination is different ... that deals with loading a selection of several such complete documents.